# Is checking a string against a number good style?

Tags: javascript

Which one of these to JS snippets are better in terms of style?

```
var answer = Number(prompt('What is the value of 2 + 2?'));

if (answer === 4) {
    // do something
}
```

vs.

```
var answer = prompt('What is the value of 2 + 2?');

if (answer == 4) {
    // do something
}
```

I'd say the first one is better because it is more explicit (and no type coercion will happen).

Comment: People have been suggesting `parseInt(n, 10)`. `+n` is equivalent and shorter. Esoteric, but well understood among JavaScript pros and you get used to it pretty quickly.

Comment: @Chris So, does +n use the parseInt function to do the conversion?

Comment: No, actually; what it does is, in my opinion, better still for this case. While `parseInt('2, perhaps', 10)` or `parseInt('2.345', 10)` will both return `2`, `+'2, perhaps'` would return `NaN` and `+'2.345'` would return `2.345` (so, a Number, but not an integer). The `+` unary operator basically calls `Number`, while `parseInt` takes the first chunk (drop whitespace, split on punctuation) and tries to take it as an integer (base as specified by the radix parameter or it guesses 8, 10 or 16 - `Number` will guess 10 or 16).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with `answer`.  If the only thing you want to do is compare it, you don't need to convert the type:

```
var answer = prompt('What is the value of 2 + 2?');

if (answer === "4") {
    // do something
}
```

If you want to end up with a number for comparison and then further processing, `Number` or the unary plus operator `+` will convert the output string to a numeric value, or `NaN` if it is not a valid base 10 number.

```
var answer = +prompt('What is the value of 2 + 2?');

if (answer === 4) {
    // do something
}
```

There is a difference between `parseInt(x, 10)` and `Number(x)` - the former will ignore non-numeric characters at the end.

```
parseInt("4Hello World"); // 4
Number("4Hello World"); //NaN
+"4Hello World"; //NaN
```

Comment: With triple-equals no string entered at the prompt will ever equal the number 4, so you might as well say `if (false)`. Surely for this particular example the whole point is to let "4" be equal to 4, hence double-equals is needed unless some other type conversion is done as in your second example?

Comment: @nnnnnn In the first example, I'm comparing a string to a string.  The point is you don't always need to do conversion.  If you need to do a conversion because you have a numeric variable being compared to `answer`, that's what the second snippet is for.

Comment: +1 My apologies, I admit I'm completely in the wrong here. I reread your answer again before posting each of my previous comments and somehow still read it as comparing to the number 4 rather than the string "4". I guess this is what happens if I post after midnight - time to get some sleep...

Answer (score 4):

They are both wrong, because you should use `parseInt(XX, 10)` for this. And remember, every time you use `==` Jesus kills a puppy. So always use `===`, and therefore: always check against the correct type.

Comment: (*looks at the source of current project*) It's a puppy holocaust!

Comment: Number will work fine - parseInt will allow answers that are not necessarily correct `parseInt("4a", 10)` will return `4` so the code will think that `"4a"` is a correct answer.

Comment: Why is it better than Number?

Comment: They're not both wrong, they're both right - just not necessarily the most appropriate for all situations. I prefer the unary + operator, but `Number()` is usually a better choice than `parseInt()` - unless you _want_ to ignore trailing non-numeric characters or you're not dealing with base 10.

Answer (score 1):

Well of course the first one because, as you mentioned, no type coercion happens.but you should use parseInt:

```
 var answer = parseInt((prompt('What is the value of 2 + 2?'), 10)) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Better would be

```
var n = prompt("What is the value of 2 + 2?");
n = parseInt(n, 10);
//and check
```